# Mapping 3rd party APIs to one API

Tags: c#, json, rest, asp.net-web-api

I'm creating a wrapper for several different 3rd party APIs to effectively expose one Web API

So my API would have something like:

```
GET http://myapi.com/cars/1
```

Response:

```
{
    "name": "DB9",
    "make": "Aston Martin",
    "speed": 123
}
```

But this would actually internally call

```
GET http://astonmartinapi.com/db/9
```

Response:

```
{
    "speed": 123
}
```

Then calling `/cars/2` would respond with `{ "name": "mondeo", "make": "Ford", "speed": 34 }` which would internally call `GET http://fordapi.com/vehicles/mondeo`.

How would one go about implementing a map from different entities on my site to these third party sites?

---

One thought I had was to create a mapper:

```
public JsonResult Get(int id = 0)
{
    var car = db.Cars.Find(id);

    // check not null, etc

    switch (car.Make.Id) // refactor into method
    {
        case 1:
            // query astonmartinapi
            break;
        case 2:
            // query fordapi
            break;
    }

    // return stuff
}
```

But this would mean hard coding stuff which isn't nice.

Any better ideas?

Comment: Since the URL is tied to the car manufacturer, why not have a related table `Manufacturers` which has a field "API URL" and for e.g any credentials you need to present, etc. Then you can simply select your car, and make an HTTP request (like ryan1234 suggested) via `car.Manufacturer.APIUrl` - as a bonus you lose the `switch` statement.

Answer (score 2):

Just a thought, but you could write an interface like this:

```
    public interface IExternalUrlProvider
    {
        string DownloadString(string baseUrl, string path);
        string GetString(string baseUri, string relativePath, string userName, string password, AuthenticationSchemes scheme);
        string Post(string baseUri, string relativePath, string userName, string password, AuthenticationSchemes scheme = AuthenticationSchemes.Basic, Dictionary<string, object> postParameters = null);
    }
```

... then you can implement it and make any generic REST call.  The bonus is that you can also mock the interface for unit testing.

The above is just an example of what you might do.  You can obviously change the return type to be a JObject (Newtonsoft JSON library) or whatever.

You could also make an interface that isn't so opinionated around making generic HTTP calls and then provide one implementation per third party.